# Do you use another terminology for bibliography when you use only links instead of books, quotes, etc.?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I am developing new software and I want to have a list of resources for the web pages that I have used to develop this software. Example of my-resources.txt:

```
- https://tutorialxyz.com/xxxx
- https://domainxyz.com/xxxx
- ...
```

Do you use bibliography for this type of file or do you use another name?

In Spanish we use `webgrafía`, maybe in English it could be `webgraphy`?

I found this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webography

**UPDATE 2019/03/17**

I asked to other software developers, in this case, one of them is from UK and the other one is from USA. They tell that they usually use "webography" but sometimes they saw "webliography" too.

Comment: Please, I have a plea: I am developing new software, no **a**.

Comment: I concur with @Lambie on this one. *Software* is a mass (uncountable) noun. Either say "developing new software", or if you want to be clear that it's one bit of software, say "developing a new *piece of* software", or "a new software *programme*".

Comment: or a new software application, or a new app [mostly for mobile phones]

Comment: @SamBC I'll just point out for the sake of pedantry that 'software program' is spelled that way, even in British English, whereas 'television programme' has the extra 'me' in Britain.

Comment: @fred2: Well, I never noticed that while living here and studying compsci, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @SamBC. I guess it could be that, in the 15 years since I left, 'program' has followed '-ize' as 'things that were fine in British English, but have been abolished so we don't look American', but going back at least as far as the ZX Spectrum and the days computers came with printed manuals, it was for decades universally 'program'.

Comment: @fred2: I wouldn't be surprised if it were something that's just completely inconsistent. I remember people trying to drum in the difference between disc and disk, but I doubt it stuck. Not that it matters as much anymore...

Comment: @SamBC. Which reminds me of my one piece of South African English. The later 'non-floppy 3.5 inch floppy disks' were called 'stiffy disks' in South Africa. People I worked with sent me "stiffies" through the post. :-0

Answer (score 1):

In English, a bibliography is a bibliography, regardless of the media referred to.

Depending on what you're doing, you may need to be careful to use it correctly. If it is a list of things you've used, or suggest that people read, that is a bibliography. In some parts of academia, this is distinguished from a *reference list*, which is a list of things *referred to in the text*.

The coinage of *webography* is still new, and mostly used when talking about such lists, rather than as the heading or title for the list. It is not a word that everyone would generally recognise. In your case, I would use bibliography, or just not use any name and say "list of web resources that were useful during development" or such.

Comment: It's also not uncommon to have a list titled ***Further Reading***, which may or may not be distinguished from a ***Reference List*** (and/or ***Bibliography**?* Not sure on that specific point).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I develop software too.

I have never heard the word 'webography' before, but I suppose it is appropriate if you are *only* including URLs of websites. It means, in essence, 'bibliography of websites'. However, it is such a new word that some people may not know what it is.

To my mind, if you are storing it as a plain text file, there is nothing wrong with calling it 'my-resources.txt', or what about the traditional 'readme.txt'?

I think it is an uncommon enough item that you can, to an extent, make up your own rules.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the neologism "webgraphy" and simply call such a list a "list of resources", "list of links to resources", "list of resource URLs" or the like. It could be called a "Bibliography of online resources".

There is the precedant of "Discology" for a list of recorded music, but I don't think "webgraphy" is well enough established for use. In fact, I am thinking that I should propose the deletion of the linked Wikipedia article.

Answer (score -1):

These experts ([how to cite software](https://www.software.ac.uk/how-cite-software)) use:

> **Software downloaded from the web:** [bolding mine in this citation]
>
> ProductName. Version. ReleaseDate. Publisher. Location. DOIorURL.
>   DownloadDate.
>
> OGSA-DAI REST. 4.2.1. December 2012. OGSA-DAI Project.
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/ogsa-dai. 27/04/2012.
>
> UltimateFFT. 2.4. December 2012. Fred Bloggs, EPCC, The University of
>   Edinburgh, UK. http://www.epcc.ed.ac.uk/ultimate-fft. 27/04/2012.
>
> C implementation of Wu's color quantizer. 2. 1991. Xiaolin Wu,
>   Department of Electrical & Computer Engineering, McMaster University,
>   Hamilton, Ontario. http://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/~xwu/cq.c. 27/04/2012.
>
> **Software checked-out from a public repository:**
>
> ProductName. Publisher. URL. CheckoutDate.
>   RepositorySpecificCheckoutInformation.
>
> OGSA-DAI REST. OGSA-DAI Project.
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/ogsa-dai. 27/04/2012. Check-out:
>   ogsa-dai/branck/ogsadai4.1/, revision 1657.
>
> **Software provided by a researcher:**
>
> ProductName. Author. Location. ContactDetails. ReceivedDate.
>   BestFFTroutine ever file. Fred Bloggs, EPCC, The University of
>   Edinburgh, UK. Fred.bloggs@epcc.ed.ac.uk. 27/04/2012.

There is a lot of useful information on the subject of citations, etc. on that site. The entry I cited seems relevant to your endeavors.

Webografia links to webography on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webography.